# Сверстать линию под заголовком

Tags: html, css

Сижу и туплю, помогите, плиз.

Как лучше сверстать такую линию под заголовком?

Поддержка старых браузеров не нужна. Чистый CSS, без лишних элементов и картинок. Желательно чтобы она увеличивалась/уменьшалась в длину в зависимости от длины заголовка.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: псевдоэлемент с абсолютным позиционированием

Comment: @humster_spb, можно и без абсолютного.

Comment: @Qwertiy, можно :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться псевдоэлементом `::after`.

```css
.title {
  display: inline-block;
  color: blue;
}

.title::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: currentColor;  /* линия будет иметь тот же цвет, что и сам заголовок */
  width: 50%;  /* длина линии будет меняться в зависимости от длины заголовка */
  margin: 10px auto 0;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="title">ЗАГОЛОВОК</h1>
```

Answer (score 3):

```css
h1 {
  width: min-content;
  margin: auto;
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

h1::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  border-bottom: .125em solid;
  margin: 0 1em;
  margin: 0 min(20%, 1em);
}
```

```html
<h1 contenteditable>Заголовок</h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вся магия из-за строчки `margin: auto`.

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: blue;
}
h1 span {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 0.25em;
}
h1 span::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  transition: 500ms ease;
  border-top-width: 4px;
  border-top-style: solid;
}
h1 span:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h1><span>Заголовок</span></h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

Всё зависит от заказчика. Можно как вариант.

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #353666;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
h1{
  font-weight: 700;
}
marker{
  display: block;
  margin: 20px auto;
  background-color:#353666;
  font-size: 2px;
  width: 8%;
}
```

```html
<h1>ЗАГОЛОВОК</h1>
<marker>...</marker>
```